# How can I see how many items I have removed from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to see how many items I have removed from a list. As you can see when I assign total I am getting how many are still in the list. What could I do to see what I took out?

```
List = [1,2,3,4]
while True:
    removeItem = input()
    if removeItem in List:
        List.remove(removeItem
        continue
    elif removeItem == "":
        total = len(List)
        print(total)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to store it before removing. ie:

```
List = [1,2,3,4]
before = len(List)

while True:
    removeItem = input()
    if removeItem in List:
        List.remove(removeItem
        continue
    elif removeItem == "":
        total = len(List)
        print(total)
        break

print before - len(list)
```

Comment: sure, you store

    before = len(List) 

will store the length of the list at the start of the run, in this case 4, so when you do:

    before - len(list)

before = 4
len(list) = the number of items on the list after substraction

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to keep count of the items removed by incrementing it whenever an item is removed.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
removed_count = 0
while True:
    print('Removed: %s' % removed_count)
    removeItem = input()
    if removeItem in List:
        List.remove(removeItem)
        removed_count += 1
        continue
    elif removeItem == "":
        total = len(List)
        print(total)
        break
```